# how can I change this Relative Paths to Absolute Paths?

Tags: php, hyperlink, absolute

for following code, I would like to know how can I change to absolutely link?

```
<a class="inline" href="<?php echo $profile->avater->full;?>" id="avater_profile_img">
    <img src="<?php echo $profile->avater->avater;?>" alt="<?php echo $profile->full_name;?>" class="responsive-img" />

    <?php 
        if((int)abs(((strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - $profile->lastseen))) < 60 && (int)$profile->online == 1) { 
            echo '<div class="useronline" style="top: 10px;left: 10px;"></div>'; 
        }
    ?>

</a>
```

Comment: i would like to change the image link to a Absolute Paths..such as http://abc .com/

Comment: Are you using this code on any CMS like WordPress?

Comment: NO..it is php website

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to makes the URL Absolute. I have added `://` as well before the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` so it may work as per currently viewing scheme either in `http` or `https`.

```
<a class="inline" href="<?php echo $profile->avater->full;?>" id="avater_profile_img">
    <img src="<?php echo '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $profile->avater->avater;?>" alt="<?php echo $profile->full_name;?>" class="responsive-img" />

    <?php 
        if((int)abs(((strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - $profile->lastseen))) < 60 && (int)$profile->online == 1) { 
            echo '<div class="useronline" style="top: 10px;left: 10px;"></div>'; 
        }
    ?>

</a>
```

EDIT:

Use `str_replace` to change `a.com` with `b.com` in the image.

```
<a class="inline" href="<?php echo $profile->avater->full;?>" id="avater_profile_img">
    <img src="<?php echo str_replace("a.com", "b.com", $profile->avater->avater); ?>" alt="<?php echo $profile->full_name;?>" class="responsive-img" />

    <?php 
        if((int)abs(((strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - $profile->lastseen))) < 60 && (int)$profile->online == 1) { 
            echo '<div class="useronline" style="top: 10px;left: 10px;"></div>'; 
        }
    ?>

</a>
```

Comment: thanks, let me tell you more details, i have 2 websites using same database, I want the image link using the A website link,can I do something like this: A.com/.$profile->avater->avater;?>

Comment: as i tested. this code forced to show the a full image link: "$profile->avater->avater; " something like: b.com/xsxsa.jpg. how can I changed to show a.com//xsxsa.jpg ??  thanks all

Comment: @leung881 Do you need to hardcode the URL to `a.com`?

Comment: @leung881 Please check the `edit` code of the above answer and just replace the `a.com` with your respective URL.

Comment: thanks but not work.. just become this:  https://www.a.com/://a.comhttps://www.a.com/upload/photos/2019/07/WncG2iOyjF126Himv2nP_full.jpg

Comment: What's the value of this: `$profile->avater->avater;` and what you have actually added?

Comment: $profile->avater->avater >> this one will become to  https://www.a.com/upload/photos/2019/07/WncG2iOyjF126Himv2nP_full.jpg

Comment: @leung881 What's their current value?

Comment: what do you mean? after added your code, it changed to https://www.a.com/://a.comhttps://www.a.com/upload/photos/2019/07/WncG2iOyjF126Himv2nP_full.jpg

Comment: Before changing what it was printing there?

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. If you focus on the output string then it is adding `a.com`, `://a.com` and `https://www.a.com` and then making the URL absolute. This can't be done with my provided answer.

Comment: before. >> a.com/upload/photos/2019/07/WncG2iOyjF126Himv2nP_full.jpg

Comment: let me repeat: now website with $profile->avater->avater , will showing : a.com/upload/photos/2019/07/WncG2iOyjF126Himv2nP_full.jp /  I want change to b.com/upload/photos/2019/07/WncG2iOyjF126Himv2nP_full.jp

Comment: @leung881 It is already printing the full URL as far as I can see it.

Comment: what do mean? so you know what I want to do?

Comment: Please check now, I have updated the `edit` answer. I think That's what you are looking for.

Comment: Till now, I am thinking that you need to convert relative URL to absolute URL but in actual you are already having the absolute but just needs to replace the domain so hope the last update answer works for you.

Comment: I have only added a single line change in your code which is working fine for me. Just add this line: `echo str_replace("a.com", "b.com", "a.com/upload/photos/2019/07/WncG2iOyjF126Himv2nP_full.jp");`

on this site: http://www.writephponline.com/

To verify that everything is fine with this line what I have updated in your code.  There should another issue in your own code.

Comment: ok..let me try again..thanks.. is it only changed to a.com. no need http s:// a.com ?

Comment: It replaces whatever you pass on it. Like `a.com` with `b.com`. or `https://a.com` with `https://b.com` and so on..